# Saml Difference between HTTP-POST and HTTP-POST-SimpleSign binding

Tags: java, digital-signature, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

Is there any difference between *urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST* and *urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign*

Does **HTTP-POST** binding assume that signature is envoloped inside SAMLRequest?

Does **HTTP-POST-SimpleSign** assume that signature is detached from XML, and present as a separate post parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Basically it doesn't us XMLsig standart but istead just signs the whole message as a blob.

Yes the signature is sent as a separate post parameter.

[spec](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/25607/sstc-saml-binding-simplesign-cd-02.pdf)